# Trouble with WebView loading, Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

I am new to this, but eager to learn. I have the following code currently working. My  application is pulling in xml data from an rss feed. Everything thus far is displaying correctly, except when I hit my back button to return to the home view.

The load time to return is very very slow, my question is, how can i improve the load time so that it is almost instant, instead of a couple seconds?

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

        import spark.components.Image;
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            navigator.popView();
        }


        protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
        {
            webView.loadString(data.description);
        }

        protected function view1_viewDeactivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
        {
            var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(webView.webView.viewPort.width, webView.webView.viewPort.height);

            webView.webView.drawViewPortToBitmapData(bitmap);

            webView.webView.stage = null;

            var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();

            var img:Image = new Image();

            img.source = jpg.encode(bitmap);

            img.x = 8;
            img.y = 24;

            addElement(img);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:navigationContent>
    <s:Button label="Back" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:navigationContent>

<controls:WebView left="8" right="8" top="24" bottom="8" id="webView"  />

<s:Label x="7" y="7" fontSize="8" text="{data.link}"/>
```